# Dynamic Accessibility Tooltip using pure JS

Tags: javascript, accessibility, tooltip

I need some ideas and guidance to create a dynamic tooltip.
Basically the tooltip will be triggered to be displayed when the keyboard focus reaches an specific component, when triggered, the tooltip will display similary from [this](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/tooltip/how-to/dynamic-tooltip-content).

After the focus is moved from the component, the tooltip will cease to exist, and whenever reaches the component again it will be created.

Note: This need to be done using JavaScript only, the HTML code must remain the same, only changed dynamically.

Comment: The way that this normally works is that you try to solve your own problem first. When you get stuck, post a reproducible code example and then you can ask for help.  If you're not sure where to start, look for code samples on the internet and try to improve on the approach others have taken.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

In general, tooltips are not easy to get right, I would recommended to find another solution:

> If the information is important enough to include as a tooltip or title, consider including it in visible text.

– [MDN `tooltip` role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/tooltip_role)

Also [the GOV.UK Design System does not even have a tooltip component](https://design-system.service.gov.uk/components/), it’s one of the most accessible ones known.

[MDN has an extensive article on the `tooltip` role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/tooltip_role), including code examples.

These still have the following **shortcomings**, as described in [Required JavaScript Features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/tooltip_role#required_javascript_features):

> - The tooltip can be hidden with the Escape key
> - The tooltip stays open when hovered

I’m trying to provide some JS solution for at least the first issue:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('password');
const tooltip = document.getElementById('passwordrules');

// hide tooltip on Escape
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === 'Escape') {
    input.classList.add('hidetooltip');
  }
});

// Allow tooltip to be shown on next hover or focus
input.addEventListener('blur', _ => input.classList.remove('hidetooltip'));
input.addEventListener('mouseout', _ =>  input.classList.remove('hidetooltip'));
```

```css
[role="tooltip"],
.hidetooltip.hidetooltip.hidetooltip + [role="tooltip"] {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
[aria-describedby]:hover,
[aria-describedby]:focus {
  position: relative;
}
[aria-describedby]:hover + [role="tooltip"],
[aria-describedby]:focus + [role="tooltip"] {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input aria-describedby="passwordrules" id="password" type="password" />
<div role="tooltip" id="passwordrules">
  <p>Password Rules:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Minimum of 8 characters</li>
    <li>
      Include at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, one number
      and one special character
    </li>
    <li>Unique to this website</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In general, if you are looking for guidance on accessible components, I recommend taking a look at the [ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/).

Unfortunately the [tooltip pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tooltip/) is not well documented yet.

The [Inclusive Components page also has some discussion on when to (not) use tooltips](https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/) and implications for assistive technology. The examples there are lacking the above mentioned features as well.

The [Lion white label web components offer an accessible tooltip](https://lion-web.netlify.app/components/tooltip/overview/) that includes these features, maybe [have a look at their JavaScript](https://github.com/ing-bank/lion/blob/master/packages/ui/components/tooltip/src/LionTooltip.js).